# simplification of 唻?

Tags: traditional-vs-simplified

**唻**

> **唻的解释**
>
> 拼音:lai4
>
> 呼声。
>
> **【本字提供国家或地区】**
>
> 中国大陆、中国台湾、日本、韩国、越南

Does 唻 not have a simplificated version?

[**ZiSea**:](http://zisea.com/content.asp?uni=181876)

[image: zisea]

**字海**:

[image: zihai]

As this ^ (above) just seems to be listed as a *variant*

Comment: Many "類推簡化" (Analogy simplification) characters haven't been included in Unicode. And some of them will be selected as extensions in the following "CJK extension area".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simplified word, and it is a rare used word. Most people will recognize it only as 哆唻咪(doreme), but now it's replaced mostly by 哆来咪，or even 多来米. 
And the word 口来, though it is said to be simplified version of 唻， in fact this may not be realy a word, it's never used, even can't be inputed by most Chinese IMEs.

Comment: it's non-unicode so it shouldn't be typeable

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say it's a simplified character (简体字). It's a traditional character (繁体字/正体字) that doesn't have a simplified version available in most fonts. And based on @Tommy's answer below, it's also a variant character (异体字) for 嚟.

Answer (score 2):

[Cantodict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/8871/) reports that this is a Cantonese word and is the simplified variant of 嚟 (per Google Translate) "Come out and walk". I would suggest having a native speaker confirm that meaning. I was able to find the 18 stroke traditional character (嚟) and key it into the computer.

[image: variant]

[image: close-up]

[Zdict](http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/569F.htm) has more information on the traditional character.

Answer (score 2):

rare word,I think it is a variant,though it have a little own meannings.

below from 汉典

◎ 唻 lài
〈动〉
(1) 慰劳 [appre ciate sb.sservices and present gifts]
劳之来之,匡之直之,辅之翼之。——《孟子·滕文公上》
莫我肯勑。——《诗·魏风·硕鼠》
贤者勑其材。——《韩非子·主道》
(2) 另见 lái
词性变化
◎ 唻
唻 lài
〈助〉
(1) 〈方〉
(2) 相当于“呢” [what]。如:你们敲锣打鼓的干什么徕?又相当于“来着”。如:娘是怎么嘱咐你徕,怎么都忘了?
(3) 相当于“啦” [really]。如:解放前放牛娃可苦唻

Answer (score 2):

Someone just up voted this and got me looking back at solutions.

does exist now.

There is an entry on [zisea](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=2BA81) mention that it is part of:

> [cjk ext. e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_E)

It was part of Unicode 8.0 and released on June 17, 2015.